# How to support other languages in Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Reading the Android Training about the "Supporting Different Languages" [1] and after running emulator, the default language is English. I.e.:

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-es/
           strings.xml
       values-fr/
           strings.xml
```

1) How can we test the emulator in view of other languages?

2) We have to install additional languages ​​to support it?

I would like to view the screen in the language in French and then Spanish. In settings of the emulator does not have these languages ​​available to choose from.

(1)
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: there will be "custom locale" in the menu of the simulator, there you change!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What emulator do you use?
On my emulator I'm able to change the language by going to `Settings -> Language & keyboard -> Select Language`

[image]

Comment: The problem was my lack of attention and had not found this option. :( Thanks for the response!

Comment: It should be pointed out that the intel emulator only comes with english, thus switching language is not supported.